# How to order script input files by their timestamp?

Tags: bash, input

I am creating a bash script in which I need to check timestamps of input data and order the files by their timestamp and finally merge them into one big data file. Timestamps can be totally random but they have to contain year, month, day and time - examples :

```
[2016-05-14 11:17:01] 0.000000
[11:17:01 2016-05-14] 0.000000
[2016 11:17:01 05-14] 0.000000
```

There will be more then 100 entries per second, so I have to choose a method that will check timestamps of two files and sort them accordingly. I have created something VERY provisional - it just appends the files :

```
for var in "$@"
do
    cat "$var" >> $TMPDIR/input #$TMPDIR/input is the big file
done
```

I don't necessarily want exact commands, an idea how to do that would be also perfect.

Comment: the lines in `$TMPDIR/input` can be sorted, they are in chronological after the sorting due to the timestamp in front of each line,

Comment: Lars Fischer remark is good. `sort` can be used to sort the lines alphabetically. Also the `for` loop is not necessary. You should try:

    `sort "$@" >> $TMPDIR/input`

Comment: @Jayjargot yes, this sound like a very good idea. however it has got a catch - I have to implement a switch to change the order so I might use this one when the timeformat is not changed. if you have any more ideas, could you please post them as an answer ?

Comment: well on the other hand, it may not be as handy as I thought it to be - because my log has got very frequent inputs in it, for example 100 entries/second - this would mess it up :/

Comment: Do you mean that timeformat in input files may vary? If yes could you edit the question and add examples? Could you try to elaborate and give more details and edit the question afterward?

Answer (score 0):

In linux you can get access/modify/change timestamp, which should be helpful.

Hope that helps, you can find commands which maintain file stats :)